# A control to display money in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, currency

I have a Ruby-on-Rails 4 HAML web application in which I need an input control to represent money in US dollars.

I've played around with some javascript, but nothing so far has been ideal.  If I just limit the type of characters, the user can still type in something like 12.222.33334.

If I can't find something better, I think I'm just going to give the user two text boxes - one for dollars, and the other for cents, and only allow them to input numbers in both, and only allow two characters for the cents box.

Still, I can't help but think there has to be something better - a specific HAML control to allow the user to input money - just like there are controls for dates, etc.  I just haven't been able to find anything so far.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: This jQuery plugin should help you achieve what you need from JS side: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Are you looking for client side validation? because with just a plain input field, this validation can be done on the model easily